# motion with friction slope

Tags: kinematics, slope, projectile-motion

box on slope

slope 3m long

angle of θ with the horizontal, where 15◦ ≤ θ ≤ 50◦

box starts from rest at the top of the slope.

sliding friction is ''mu''=0.2

---

Show that the speed (in ms^-1)of the box at the bottom of the slope is
given by

sqrt (6g(sinθ − 0.2cosθ))

---

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: acceleration on the slope for the object: $g(\sin \theta-\mu \cos \theta)$ and   $v^2-u^2=2as$ and here, $u=0 ms^{-1}$ and s=$3m$. Easy to compute?

Comment: perfect... so the sqrt comes from the velocity^2 part. i was thinking it was to do with ¦F¦=sin0-cos0

so i am to use the equation V^2 = Vo^2+2ax 

but rearrange it

Comment: What did you get as the answer?

Comment: i didnt. i was just asked to show that that is what i use to obtain the acc at bottom of slope not to solve

Comment: so this is my answer. (worth 5 marks)

Comment: Lol you may accept something worth 15 rep xD

Comment: so this is my answer. (worth 5 marks)

we know x=3
mu = 0.2
Vo= 0

equation for a is g(sin(theta)-'mu'cos(theta))
= g(sin(theta)-0.2cos(theta))

subbing these into the equation      v^2=vo^2+2ax        gives

v^2=0^2+2*3*g(sin(theta)-0.2cos(theta))

so v=sqrt (above)

Comment: repped you but it doesnt count as i only have 11 rep

Comment: I was just kidding. Relax xD

Comment: hehe. thanks for your help :P